90s anime\cartoon with a boy whose father might be an alien
What I remember is that, the mother was killed in the beginning of the 1st episode by some orb-like thing. As he gets older, I remember him meeting some old man in the desert with a pet alien and gets a hold of a blue motorcycle that can hover. And the last episode I remember seeing was about his father, he had some sort of eye patch on and was assumed to be dead, who was an alien I believe.

Was this a movie or a cartoon series?  Because it almost sounds like Heavy Metal (1981).  There were 4 or 5 "episodes" within the movie, but they all centered around the orb and its power.

I believe it was a cartoon series or anime series, the art work seemed more Japanese at the time. It aired late night forgot which channel around 9ish or so at it was a series.

@Walt Are you sure on this one.

@AJ Yes. Unless it's another animated miniseries with a kid on a hoverbike whose father is an alien with an eyepatch. ;)

@Walt Ok then :)

You're looking for DreamWorks' animated miniseries Invasion America that aired on the WB in 1998.

A young crossbreed human and alien fights to keep both of his worlds from going to war. His father, an alien (Tyrusian) emperor and his mother, a human, are both missing, and the young man (David) has to discover who his friends and enemies really are.

His mom is sucked into an orb in the first (2-part) episode, he has a blue hover-bike and his alien dad appears later on sporting an eyepatch. The show is currently available on Youtube; Here's the episode that features his dad:



